# Where can i find some stylish sliders for my website?

Tags: web-development

Is there a site where I can download or generate some stylish sliders like the one below?

I mean just as an image for the background of my slider.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) package - it supplies really nice UI widgets, including a [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) similar to the widget you are looking for.

I tend to use jQuery UI for my sites when I need a slider.